# Can't get two columns in Bootstrap Grid

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, grid, google-visualization

I have an asp.net Web form where I'm using Bootstrap.
Inside the container div, I have 10 piecharts made by the google charts api.
I want to have these charts in two columns, five in each.

It's okay to do this in normal HTML tabel where I set the width and hight like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="Q7piechart" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"/>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id="Q8piechart" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I want to use Bootstrap grid, so it can be responsive.

I try this:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div id="Q9piechart" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"/>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div id="Q10piechart" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"/>
      </div> 
</div>
```

And this

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div id="Q9piechart" style="width: 70%"/>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div id="Q10piechart" style="width: 70%"/>
      </div> 
</div>
```

I've also tried the "span6" class for columns.
The container div is about 1170px when I lode the page.
But the charts in the grid is always in the same column.
What I'm I doing wrong?

[image: Charts from grid inside Red line]

**EDIT**

This is how the Javascript looks like (the code who make my chart);

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Svært enig', 'Antall'],
      ['Enig',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Q9piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** :
`<div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div id="Q9piechart"   ></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div id="Q10piechart" ></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>`

Specify the Width of chart in Options

**EDIT** : `var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"50%"},
      width: 320
    };`

Comment: No, then my charts disappeared. Maybe you can have a look at my javascript that makes the piechart?

Comment: yes  make a pastebin or jsfiddle of the scripts and css

Comment: Css is just default bootstrap 3 and I have written the JS in the edit of my question. Tell me if you want complet code.

Comment: It works, but I needed to remove the left og top attribut to show the title.